# Xcode 11.4 compile time error "Content and frame layout guides before iOS 11.0"

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

A compile error appeared after I updated Xcode to **11.4 (11E146)** - `Content and frame layout guides before iOS 11.0` in storyboard, which prevents the projec from build. Does anyone know what has been changed whith this latest update and where the error comes from? 
Obviously before the update everything was fine.

Comment: @matt well will discuss it with PO but anyway I'm curious what's going on here

Comment: Check your scrollview/tableview. Open size inspector (ruler icon on top of right side panel.) Ensure checkbox "Content Layout Guides" disabled.

Comment: @NikolayTabunchenko I thought of that but then why does the problem arise only in 11.4? and how to reproduce? I can't

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before the update it was mistakenly *not* producing a build error. The fact that there is now an error is actually a bug fix.

If you target an OS earlier than iOS 11, you cannot use the Content and Frame layout guides in your storyboard because they were not introduced until iOS 11. Using them like this will cause crashes in iOS 10 and below. To get rid of this error you can either stop using the layout guides or target a higher iOS version.

If you think you have eliminated all references to these layout guides in your storyboards but are still seeing this error, be sure to check your UITextViews too!

Comment: Xcode is adding the content and frame automatically when I drag in a UIView and not allowing me to delete them. How do I get rid of them. ( want to target iOS 10.)

Comment: @user6631314 Open size inspector (ruler icon on top of right side panel.) Ensure checkbox "Content Layout Guides" disabled. - NikolayTabunchenko

Answer (score 4):

You are using storyboards make sure to update the deployment target

[image]

Comment: Best answer! thanks

Comment: This! It's quite easy to miss it. I was checking the project target and it was above iOS 11. I was completely clueless. Thank you very much!